# Licensing concerns with webjars?

Tags: javascript, webjars

This might seem like a dumb question, but are there any licensing concerns I should be aware of when deploying a commercial application which manages JS dependencies via webjars, other than the individual licenses of the JS sources themselves?

Comment: Questions about licensing are off-topic for Stack Overflow. This question might be better suited at [programmers.se].

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebJars are really just a Maven build that packages up the assets from a web library into a Jar file that is published on Maven Central.  The build that does the packaging uses the same license as the upstream assets.  So as long as you are ok with the upstream license you shouldn't have to worry about using the WebJar.